# firefox jquery.load ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I'm having trouble with the following function to load content into a target div. It works fine on chrome & Safari, but on firefox (27.0.1, but i'm guessing all) it returns the alert with a value of message "0 error".

```
$("#somediv").on('click', 'a', function(){
  theURL ='/product/get/53';
  $('#thetargetdiv').load(theURL, function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status === "error") { alert( response + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText ); }  
  });   
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

I've tried a few things but cannot make it work in firefox.

On initial page load firefox does log:

"Error: http://samplesite.com/public/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one" -- which I am unsure what it relates to. Other browsers do not report this.

Many thanks,

Tom

Comment: You can ignore the sourcemap error (which is really just a warning.) To make it go away, use the newest version of jquery or include the sourcemap correctly.

Comment: Great - I didn't think it would be the cause, just thought better to add in just in case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass event as parameter of anonymous function, FF doesn't pass it implicitely:

```
$("#somediv").on('click', 'a', function(event){...});
```

EDIT: now I'm wondering how could it be relevant to your issue but anyway, should be said... Could it be the load() request being aborted if your anchor tag click makes any redirection?! Not sure how FF handles it.

Comment: `event` simply isn't a global var in firefox the same way it is in other browsers.

Comment: Perfect! adding in the event - fixed it. Phew. That was quick and painless. I spent all my time looking at the load() didn't occur the me it could be the cause. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @a-wolff Follow up question: It' not happening in any other part of the code, but should I  update everything with something similar to `$("#somediv").on('click', 'a', function(){` to be `$("#somediv").on('click', 'a', function(event){` For good practice?

Comment: It won't hurt anything if you do.